# Is there documentation on Datastage Designer/Directory commandline options?

Tags: datastage

I connect to several different environments (services tier: dev, test, staging, prod) with several different usernames and several different projects.

I have figured out that running `{dsdesign,director}.exe host.com/projectname` will fill the 'Attach to Project' dialog project field.

But I cannot figure out how to fill the 'Host name of the services tier' and 'User name' fields from the command line. And I cannot find any documentation in the IBM documentation. `dsdesign.exe /?` just fills the project field with `/?`.

Am I missing something, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using /D and /H switches.
[https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.doc/topics/r_ddesref_Requesting_a_Job_Report_from_the_Command_Line.html](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.doc/topics/r_ddesref_Requesting_a_Job_Report_from_the_Command_Line)

Comment: That link goes to an error page ('The requested page does not exist or might have moved.') Using `/D blah` first fills the project field with `D:/` and everything else is ignored. Same if I use `/H blah` first.

Comment: You could search in the Knowledge Center.  I am finding the page. Syntax is:

dsdesign.exe /AF=authfile | 
/D=domain /H=hostname [/U=username [/P=password]]
project (job_name | job_sequence_name | /SC shared_container_name)
/R
[/RP=report_pathname]
[/RT=stylesheet_pathname]
[/RX]

Comment: Go to Knowledge Center https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.productization.iisinfsv.home.doc/topics/kc_homepage_IS.html

Search for "generating a report using dsdesign command line DataStage"

Open "Requesting a report from the command line" link.